# CStdioFile Handle Leak

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm using a memory validation program that is reporting handles left in use at program termination. I've narrowed it down to `CStdioFile` calls. Seems that any `CStdioFile` opened in `InitInstance` or in the main window dialog's `OnInitDialog` in a Dialog app, leave handles lying around.

This is more of a curiosity than a problem but I'd like to understand it in case it **is** a problem and I'm interpreting it wrong.

So, I took a small app (`InitInstance` shown here) and put a bit of code in to test it and, sure enough, I get a handle leak. If I change the `CStdioFile` to `CFile` and open the file, it doesn't report a leak.

I put the open in braces to see if having it destruct after use would fix it. I tried specifically closing the file and it doesn't help.

```
BOOL CMyApp::InitInstance()
{
    AfxEnableControlContainer();

    {
    CStdioFile fFile;  // Change to a CFile to get no leaks.
    fFile.Open("mytestfile.txt", CFile::modeRead);
    }


    // Standard initialization
    // If you are not using these features and wish to reduce the size
    //  of your final executable, you should remove from the following
    //  the specific initialization routines you do not need.

#ifdef _AFXDLL
    //Enable3dControls();           // Call this when using MFC in a shared DLL
#else
    Enable3dControlsStatic();   // Call this when linking to MFC statically
#endif

    CMyDlg dlg;
    m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
    int nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
    if (nResponse == IDOK)
    {

    }
    else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
    {

    }

    // Since the dialog has been closed, return FALSE so that we exit the
    //  application, rather than start the application's message pump.
    return FALSE;
}
```

I'd like to see no leaks to know the code is clean. And I'm really curious about why `CFile` and `CStdioFile` would behave differently.

Comment: You should be able to step into the MFC source to see what handles it's opening and closing.

Comment: I don't see a leak using `_CrtMemCheckpoint` etc. MFC has its own initialization, it might be picked up as leaks by external programs. Maybe try to see if using `CStdioFile` twice in a row will double the leak.

Comment: How do you check there is a leak? With which tool?

Comment: @WernerHenze - is a program called Memory Validator from Software Verify. A pretty amazing tool and it uncovered a lot of stuff the compiler and Application Verifier didn't. I never figured this particular issue out though.